# DELL Server RAID Exception - Resyncing

Tags: raid, dell, synchronization, raid1

Today they brought this old DELL server with 2 HDD initialized in RAID 1 Array. The server was used as a syslog aggregator for a long time and I was tasked to to some maintenance before we return the server to our customer. When I turned it on imediatly upon boot it displayed this warning:

```
Integrated RAID Exception Detected:
        Volume (00:004) is currently in state RESYNCING
Enter the SAS Configuration utility to investigate.
```

Immediately after the POST, the GRUB Loader starter but I was somewhat reluctunt to boot the linux os, so I restarted the server and entered the SAS to examine the problem.

When I entered the SAS utility I opened the RAID Array properties - the image bellow:

[image]

Now as you may see the Status is 0% and the drive PA07 status is Not Synced.
After several minutes I noticed that the status changed to 1% and after that to 2% and so on.

**Is it advisable to boot the OS or should I wait until the sync is complete?**

Also what will happen if I boot the OS? Will it disrupt the sync? There is a Debian Linux (SLAX distro) on that server with mysql database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drive "resync" occurs if a drive swap happens and the RAID is being rebuilt by the system. In RAID 1, this means copying the entire drive.

You can use the OS as normal, but it's will noticeably slow and during sync you do *not* have redundancy as the RAID is in a degraded state.